# Suppressing PHPLint's "operator applied to a value of type mixed"

Tags: php, lint

I am currently in a phase of work to 'bullet-proof' my code (its nice to have the time to do it!). I'm using PHPLint which is doing the job admirably, however does anyone know how to suppress the error "operator applied to a value of type mixed". Below is a sample of a function taken from a class:

```
protected /*.int.*/ function numRows(/*.string.*/ $sql)
{
    /*.int.*/ $num_rows = 0;
    $result = $this->mysqli->query($sql);

    if ($result instanceof mysqli_result)
    {
        $num_rows = $result->num_rows;
        $result->free();
    }
    return $num_rows;
}
```

This gives the following ERRORS:

```
            $num_rows = $result->num_rows;
                                 \_ HERE
```

==== DatabaseObject.class.php:103: ERROR: `->' operator applied to a value of type mixed

```
            $result->free();
                     \_ HERE
```

==== DatabaseObject.class.php:104: ERROR: `->' operator applied to a value of type mixed

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the [cast](http://www.icosaedro.it/phplint/phplint2/doc/reference.htm?p=typecasting) function to do this. However, it means installing the lint library as part of your main code. This isn't something I've been willing to do.